# Is it possible to alter the tint color of a UITabBarController AFTER it has been initialized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, overriding, ibaction

I am making an app, and I want to the able to change the tint color of the UITabBarController. I created a custom class for UITabBarController and assigned it to the UITabBar in IB. It works fine. This class has an IBAction that changes it's color called alterColor:

That's all fine and well when the app first launches. But after that, I can not seem to run that action from another class. I have a settings class, where I try to change the color. I get the correct instance by doing the following in the settings class.

.H

`@property (nonatomic, strong) TabBarController *tabController;`

.M

```
@implementation LogbookThirdViewController
@synthesize CarbsTextField;
@synthesize tabController;
```

...

```
-(IBAction)colorRedPicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *writableDBPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"colorChoice.txt"];

    NSString *carbRatio = @"red";

    [carbRatio writeToFile:writableDBPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSString *readFile;
    readFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Color = %@", readFile);
    readFile = nil;

    [tabController alterColor:tabController];  //This line should run the method.


}
```

However, nothing happens.

Comment: "Nothing happens" as in the method does not get hit in the debugger or that is has no visible effect?

Comment: I didn't try the debugger. However I have a log statement at the very beginning of alterColor:, however it never appears in the console.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem. It is that I never set TabBarController's instance to tabController (from the settingsController). However, I don't know how to do this, as neither are being created in code.

Comment: @Josiah, try my answer - i hope i didn't confuse you with a series of mini-edits...

Comment: @HeWas, I don't understand how your answer helps. I need to run a method inside a custom class.  You are creating a new property which does not concern my own dilemma. Or does it somehow? I need that custom class for other things as well.

Comment: No i'm not creating a new property .. that property is part of the UIViewController class which you inherit in your custom ViewController. It allows you to access your containing Tab bar controller - which in your case is customised...

Comment: I see. But could you explain typecasting. Right now it is not letting me use alterColor:

Comment: If I got all the types right, and you really want to pass the controller as a parameter too instead of the color; TabBarController *myController = (TabBarController *)self.tabBarController; [myController alterColor:myController];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this viewController is contained within your tabbarController, you don't need that property.

There is an existing property on UIViewController:

```
 @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController
```

(you don't need to add that in code, it is in the class you inherit from when you make your viewController sublcass)

Refer to the tabBarController thus:

```
self.tabBarController
```

You *may* need to typecast it to your custom controller to encourage the compiler to allow you to send your colorchanging method to it. But either way you will be getting the message to the correct object.